# What's the publication history for the Kiasyd Bloodline?

Tags: world-of-darkness, history-of-gaming, product-identification, vampire-the-masquerade

The Kiasyd are a Lasombra Bloodline with Fae blood in them, which makes them a rather interesting take of vampire in general. However, trying to figure out the background for them is a little complicated, since bloodlines are not in the standard books for the 2nd edition and even the Revised edition doesn't even *mention* them in the core book.

When and where was the Kiasyd Bloodline introduced as a sub-splat and in which books it appears subsequently until (and including) the 20th Anniversary Edition? Note that novels are out of the scope of this question.

<sup>As far as I know, it has not yet appeared in 5th edition, but to future-proof, this edition is specifically cut.</sup>

Comment: The bloodlines weren't in the core books for Second Edition; they appeared in the Storyteller's Companion, which came with the screens. That's where we saw the Salubri, the Daughters of Cacophony, the Samedi, the Gargoyles, and the Caitiff writeups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules and story information for the Kiasyd bloodline appear in the following books:

**Second Edition:**

- *Storytellers Handbook to the Sabbat* (1993) - first appearance

**Revised Edition:**

- *Guide to the Sabbat* (1999), p 62-63; 106-108

**Twentieth Anniversary Edition (V20):**

- *Vampire: The Masquerade* (2011), p 404-405, 455-457
- *Vampire: The Dark Ages* (2015), p 88-89
- *The Black Hand: A Guide to the Tal’Mahe’Ra* (2016), p 167-168
- *Lore of the Bloodlines* (2017), p 51-61

(Some online references list the Kiasyd as appearing in *The Player’s Guide to the Sabbat* for second edition, but this is an error; they only appear in the Storytellers Handbook.)